# JUnit type safe assertEquals

Tags: java, junit

Is there a method, that would prohibit me to call assertEquals() for different types at compilation time? I would like this code not to be compilable:

```
    String s = "foo";
    Integer i = 1;
    assertEquals(s, i);
```

EDIT: It is because during refactoring I changed a returning type of one getter of the tested class, but my Unit tests were still compilable. They failed when they were started, but this is not good enough.

Comment: Please explain why you want to have such a method.

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: It is because during refactoring I changed a returning type of one getter of the tested class, but my Unit tests were still compilable. They failed when they were started, but this is not good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Junit Matcher API:

```
    String s = "foo";
    Integer i = 1;
    assertThat(s, equalTo(i));
```

this would give you an error at compile time and some think it is convenient on top, because you can also use other matchers than equals.